# When is the module of Kähler differentials reflexive?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an affine $k$-algebra and $\Omega_{A|k}$ the module of Kähler differentials of $A$? Under what conditions on $A$ is $\Omega_{A|k}$ a reflexive $A$-module? Clearly, $A$ being smooth is sufficient since this is equivalent to $\Omega_{A|k}$  being projective. What else can be said?